# What requirements does Ant place on attribute names?

Tags: java, ant

I can get my scriptdef to run but only if I use certain names for my attributes. Apparently names like "property" and "prop1", "prop2", etc. are ok, but most other names (including "propN") are not ok. Which ones are OK and why?

This works (using attribute name ***prop2***):

```
<project name="Ant Is Weird">
  <property name="hostname" value="abc-de-fghijk0.lmn.opqr.stu"/>

  <scriptdef name="hostSubstring" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="text" />
    <attribute name="prop1" />
    <attribute name="prop2" />
    <![CDATA[
      var hn = attributes.get("text");
      project.setProperty(attributes.get("prop1"), hn.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
      project.setProperty(attributes.get("prop2"), hn.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
      ]]>
  </scriptdef>

  <target name="test" description="helps me learn about scriptdef">
    <echo message="hostname is ${hostname}"/>
    <hostSubstring text="${hostname}" prop1="firstProp" prop2="secondProp"/>
    <echo message="firstProp is ${firstProp}" />
    <echo message="secondProp is ${secondProp}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

output:

> ```
> $ ant test
> Buildfile: /apps/antTest/build.xml
>
> test:
>      [echo] hostname is abc-de-fghijk0.lmn.opqr.stu
>      [echo] firstProp is 0
>      [echo] secondProp is 0
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
> Total time: 0 seconds
> ```

But this fails (using attribute name ***propN***):

```
<project name="Ant Is Weird">
  <property name="hostname" value="abc-de-fghijk0.lmn.opqr.stu"/>

  <scriptdef name="hostSubstring" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="text" />
    <attribute name="prop1" />
    <attribute name="propN" />
    <![CDATA[
      var hn = attributes.get("text");
      project.setProperty(attributes.get("prop1"), hn.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
      project.setProperty(attributes.get("propN"), hn.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
      ]]>
  </scriptdef>

  <target name="test" description="helps me learn about scriptdef">
    <echo message="hostname is ${hostname}"/>
    <hostSubstring text="${hostname}" prop1="firstProp" propN="secondProp"/>
    <echo message="firstProp is ${firstProp}" />
    <echo message="secondProp is ${secondProp}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

output:

> ```
> $ ant test
> Buildfile: /apps/antTest/build.xml
>
> test:
>      [echo] hostname is abc-de-fghijk0.lmn.opqr.stu
>
> BUILD FAILED
> /apps/antTest/build.xml:17: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at java.util.Hashtable.containsKey(Hashtable.java:335)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.PropertyHelper.setProperty(PropertyHelper.java:640)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.setProperty(Project.java:538)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:8)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:446)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
>         at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.script.ScriptDef.executeScript(ScriptDef.java:350)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.script.ScriptDefBase.execute(ScriptDefBase.java:50)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
>
> Total time: 0 seconds
> ```

In case it matters:

> ```
> $ cat /etc/redhat-release
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
> $ ant -version
> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
> ```

Comment: d`d ` hi `24                        23                       22                      21                     20                    19                   18                  17                 16                15               14              13             12            11           `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes are lower-cased automatically. I found this out by putting

```
self.log(attributes);
```

into the script.

So if you change your script to use `propn` instead of `propN` it works:

```
project.setProperty(attributes.get("propn"), hn.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
```

This is documented in the [`Scriptdef` task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html):

> Note: Ant will turn all attribute and element names into all lowercase names, so even if you use `name="SomeAttribute"`, you'll have to use `"someattribute"` to retrieve the attribute's value from the attributes collection.